# I have created a dynamic drop down pick list that gets to a single row; how do I make that row a variable?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function initializeData(){ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("cars_view");

  var selectedCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var selectedMake = ss.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  var selectedModel = ss.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  var selectedYear = ss.getRange(2, 3).getValue();
  var selectedTrim = ss.getarange(2, 4).getvalue();
  var cars_raw =     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("cars_raw");
  // I think this is where I should be getting finale range or changing     selected row to variable 

  var trims = [];  
  var carData = getCarData();
  for (var i = 0; i < carData.length; i++) {
    var row = carData[i];
    var make = row[0];
    var model = row[1];
    var year = row[2];
    var trim = row[3];
    var data = row[$];// this is not a drop down 
    if (trim == "") {
      continue;
    }
    if (make == selectedMake && model == selectedModel && year ==  selectedYear && trim == selectedTrim  /* && data.indexOf(data)== -1*/) {
      data.push(data);
    }
  }
   // in case of no trims available
  if (!trims.length) trims = ['N/A'];

}




function onEdit() {
  Logger.log("onEdit()");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var selectedCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var cars_raw =     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("cars_raw");

  Logger.log("Hello.");

  if (sheet.getName() != "cars_view") {// changed sheet 7 to cars_view
    return;
  }

  var selectedRow = selectedCell.getRow();
  var selectedColumn = selectedCell.getColumn();
  Logger.log("selected row=%s, column=%s", selectedRow,     selectedColumn);
  // Why does this below not start with 0 and go to 3; 
  if (selectedRow == 2.0) { 
  if (selectedColumn == 1.0) {
      // make
      initializeModels();
    } else if (selectedColumn == 2.0) {
      // model
      initializeYears();
    } else if (selectedColumn == 3.0) {
      // year
      initializeTrims();
    } else if (selectedColumn == 4.0) {
      initializeData();

  }
  }
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13TorBfSBw8OtnWRKaF4hSVoCj28fIyd9roZORbyr7jU/edit#gid=896489113

Comment: I'm not sure what you want.  You'll need to describe what the process is.  What is the starting point?  What is the expected end result?

Comment: The background sheet cars_raw is where we fill in the information to populate cars_view; each car make, model, year, trim selected on cars_view drop down  narrows down to a single row in cars-raw. After the first four columns are used to narrow down selection columns E to EX is the information to fill out cars_view.

Comment: After edit data is selected the variable is which row you are getting information from then the rest is static information, one cell in cars_raw will equal the same cell in cars_view  // TODO
 // CAN THIS BE DONE BY DATA VALIDATION IN CARS_VIEW, AND ONLY THE VARIABLE OF WHICH LINE CHANGING IS ONLY NEEDED TO RESET DATA DISPLAY ?
  // If A2 True
  // If B2 True
  // If C2 True
  // If D2 True
  // then populate
  // cars_raw E  will be A6 cars_view
  // cars_raw F will be B6 cars_view
  // cars_raw G will be C6 cars_view
  // cars_raw H will be D6 cars_view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to copy values `Ex:Hx` from `cars_raw` sheet to `A6:D6` of `cars_view` sheet.

For that, you can use [`setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) method of `Range` class

```
function initializeData(){ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("cars_view");
  var selectedCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var selectedMake = ss.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  var selectedModel = ss.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  var selectedYear = ss.getRange(2, 3).getValue();
  var selectedTrim = ss.getRange(2, 4).getValue();
  var cars_raw = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("cars_raw");

  var trims = [];  
  var carData = getCarData();
  for (var i = 0; i < carData.length; i++) {
    var row = carData[i];
    var make = row[0];
    var model = row[1];
    var year = row[2];
    var trim = row[3];
    var data = row[4];
    var battery_info = row.slice(4);
    if (trim == "") {
      continue;
    }
    if (make === selectedMake && model === selectedModel && year === selectedYear && trim === selectedTrim)
    {
       var range = ss.getRange("A6:D6");
       range.setValues([battery_info]);
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

---

I've changed the `onEdit` function as follows

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var source = e.source;
  var sheet_name  = source.getSheetName();
  var range  = e.range;
  var cars_raw = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("cars_raw");

  if (sheet_name != "cars_view") {
    return;
  }

  var selectedRow = range.getRow();
  var selectedColumn = range.getColumn();
  Logger.log("selected row=%s, column=%s", selectedRow, selectedColumn);

  if (selectedColumn == 4 && selectedRow == 2) {
    initializeData();   
  }
}
```

I also had to change `getCarData` function

```
function getCarData() {
  var cars_raw = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("cars_raw");
  return cars_raw.getSheetValues(3, 1, 5000, 8);
}
```

Comment: Peculiar thing; A6 to D6 does update on cars_view to the information from cars_raw but only after manually running script initializeData, rather then when you make the finale selection of Trim. I did change battery_info to battery_size just to keep information consistent.

Comment: @JoshuaEcvHaislip: I've removed everything else for debugging and ended up with the code above. It worked perfectly for me. Please try this out. If you found this answer useful, do accept the answer

Comment: I added a line to auto refresh because it was not updating if Trim didn't have multiply choices

Comment: **bold**function onEdit(e) {
  var source = e.source;// this only errors when ran in editor. common behavor 
  var sheet_name  = source.getSheetName();
  var range  = e.range;
  var cars_raw = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("cars_raw");

  if (sheet_name != "cars_view") {
    return;
  }

  var selectedRow = range.getRow();
  var selectedColumn = range.getColumn();
  Logger.log("selected row=%s, column=%s", selectedRow, selectedColumn);

  if (selectedColumn == 4 && selectedRow == 2) {
    initializeData();   
  }
}

Comment: Now I am looking at applying  Logger.log(battery_size);
      var range = ss.getRange("A6:D6");
      range.setValues([battery_size]);
      continue; to the other 300 cells I need to update

Comment: It is progress in the right direction; I am very novice at this.